# How to retrieve Image from a link inside a data extension field in an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension which has field names "links" and "Interest". Filed Links  contains HTML links to certain images which are hosted on our internal server.

I would like to create an email which will show the image for subscriber with interest A and show another image for subscriber with interest B.

Please let me know how can I achieve this (to show images in an email from data extension  links )

Comment: I have gone through that question but that seems to be a bit different :|

Comment: How so?  Your question is the same premise -- how to parse a URL out of a string.

Comment: so, I can get the URL based on the interest a subscriber and pull it in the HTML email but I would like to show image in that email NOT URL in that email, this is what I would like to know is it possible to show or display image within the email from a data extension.